# Orbeon Forms - Handling service response

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon Forms as my form builder. I have modified "submit" button of the Form Builder to have custom behaviors, please look at my snippet below:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*">
save()
then send(
    uri             = "{xxf:property('ORBEON_API')}/api/submitForm",
    replace         = "none",
    method          = "POST",
    content         = "xml",
    content-type    = "application/xml",
    nonrelevant     = "keep",
    serialization   = "application/xml"
)
then set-workflow-stage(name = "submitted")
then success-message("save-success")
```

Now, I am trying to get response of the send() action but can't really find a document describing how to do this in Orbeon CE. I plan to receive an URI from this "{xxf:property('ORBEON_API')}/api/submitForm" so that I can use it to navigate to another page.

I found it is possible to store an Action's response into dataset using Action Settings in PE edition. Sadly, I am using the CE one.

My question is that: Is there a way/workaround for storing and manipulating Action's response in Orbeon CE? Any suggestions are much appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: I am trying to use 'replace=all' in my send() action.

Comment: You can use `replace = "all"` if the service returns the HTML and you want to show that HTML to users. But if it returns XML, based on which you'll decide where to go, use `replace = "instance"`, so the result is stored in the `fr-send-submission-response` instance (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, actions in processes can't return data, and this is really what you would want here (see [#1688](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1688)). However, `send()` stores the XML returned by your service in an instance called `fr-send-submission-response`. So you can access that instance and extract information returned by your service. From XPath, you'd use the following to access that instance:

```
xxf:instance('fr-send-submission-response')
```

For instance, the following will make a GET request on a URL that returns breakfast menu, and show the first item on the menu as the success message. (Yes, I know, this isn't a very realistic example! But at least it is one that anyone should be be able to run locally.)

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.submit.*.*">
    send(
        method  = "GET",
        uri     = "https://www.w3schools.com/XML/simple.xml",
        replace = "instance"
    )
    then success-message(
        message = "First item on the menu: {xxf:instance('fr-send-submission-response')/food[1]/name}"
    )
</property>
```

The success message will show like:

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, for some reason, `replace = "instance"` does not work for me. When I tried to use it, I received an error while `send()` is being executed.

I am using Orbeon CE build no: orbeon-2020.1.2.202103050030-CE. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @PhucNguyen I've expanded my answer above to include an example, which you should be able to run as-is, to see if the `replace = "instance"` works for you. You'll let me know how it goes! -Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the example. Let's me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: @PhucNguyen , you'll let me know if it works for you! -Alex

Comment: @PhucNguyen Just curious: did you get to check if using `replace="instance"`, and then using `xxf:instance('fr-send-submission-response')` to access the result from the `send()` works for you?